# inspect jquery-ui autocomplete list with google chrome?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, autocomplete

I am using the jquery ui autocomplete, I am overwriting the _renderItem method.

However I am having issues with the list becoming too wide when I add some divs to each li.

I want to inspect the list using google chromes developer tools, however the list keeps closing so I cannot inspect it.

How can I inspect the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set your options for closing the list to something other than the default?

I tried the example on jQuery http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source and could with ease "right click" a list item and select "inspect element", making it appear in the Dev tool's inspect window

Answer (score 3):

Select an item from the autocomplete drop down and then right click the input on the form and select inspect element.  You'll see a  list just below it that has display set to none.  Simply disable that attribute in the styles window on the right, and the list will be visible in the html.  You can then inspect any part of it...

Comment: when i click "inspect" after clicking - autocomplit list is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Try this : $("#search_input").trigger('keyup');

Answer (score 0):

I found it effective to use the [search](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/autocomplete/#method-search) method to open the results menu via the console.

`$(selector).autocomplete('search', 'substring');`